# Using websockets in spring, how do I send multiple updating messages?

Tags: spring, websocket

In the example given here https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/ , one receives data and then returns a second later with another data structure. How would I amend this to send multiple data elements if (for example) the server is processing data ?

````
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
    // I would like to send initial data here
        Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
    // I would like to send more data here (after a bit more server side processing)
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

(in kotlin). Argh.. this does not work - it sends it to *all* clients

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController() {

    var template: SimpMessagingTemplate? = null

    @Autowired
    constructor(_template: SimpMessagingTemplate) : this() {
        this.template = _template
    }

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    fun greet(greeting: String) {
        repeat(5) { i ->
            this.template!!.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", Greeting("Iteration $i"));
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        }
    }
}
```